# Cox regression output in xtable - choosing rows/columns and adding a confidence interval

Tags: r, cox-regression

I wan't to export the output from a cox regression to a table that I then can put into my article. I guess the best way to go about it is with xtable:

```
library(survival)
data(pbc)
fit.pbc <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age + edema + log(bili) + 
    log(protime) + log(albumin), data=pbc)

summary(fit.pbc)
library(xtable)
xtable(fit.pbc)
```

Now I want to do the following to the output:

- Add confidence interval (CI) of 95 %
- Select certain rows, say age and log(protime)
- Round the exp(B) & CI to three decimals
- Remove the column with z & regular coef

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd approach this by first taking a look at how the `survival` package constructs the table it prints by default.

To find the function that does that printing, examine the class of your fit object, and then look for a print method for that class:

```
class(fit.pbc)
# [1] "coxph"
grep("coxph", methods("print"), value=TRUE)
# [1] "print.coxph"         "print.coxph.null"   
# [3] "print.coxph.penal"   "print.summary.coxph"
```

After taking a look at `print.coxph`, here's what I came up with:

```
cox  <- fit.pbc

# Prepare the columns
beta <- coef(cox)
se   <- sqrt(diag(cox$var))
p    <- 1 - pchisq((beta/se)^2, 1)
CI   <- round(confint(cox), 3)

# Bind columns together, and select desired rows
res <- cbind(beta, se = exp(beta), CI, p)
res <- res[c("age", "log(protime)"),]

# Print results in a LaTeX-ready form
xtable(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the simple solution that I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

```
xtable(round(summary(fit.pbc)$conf.int[c(1,3),],3))
#-----------------------------#
% latex table generated in R 2.13.1 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Sat Oct 15 18:36:04 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & exp(coef) & exp(-coef) & lower .95 & upper .95 \\ 
  \hline
age & 1.04 & 0.96 & 1.02 & 1.06 \\ 
  log(bili) & 2.37 & 0.42 & 2.02 & 2.79 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This shows what you see with str on the summary-object

```
str(summary(fit.pbc))
# snipped
 $ conf.int    : num [1:5, 1:4] 1.0404 2.4505 2.3716 10.8791 0.0815 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "age" "edema" "log(bili)" "log(protime)" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "exp(coef)" "exp(-coef)" "lower .95" "upper .95"
```

Comment: You can also use the `digits` argument to `xtable` rather than sending it through `round`.

Comment: I think summary already rounded to 2 digits. (But there is rarely enough precision to justify more than 2 digits anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, chose Josh's answer since it solves all my issues. @DWin - I specified 3 digits because summary rounds to 2 digits - I have a very large dataset and I haven't yet decided on the amount of decimals although I completely agree that many decimals give a false perception of statistics being a more precise than they are.